# Adding additional data to Raphael.js text element

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, raphael

I am working on some sort of graph in `Raphael.js`, I made it first with D3 ([which can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/Warforce/7f5SZ/49/)), but that didn't work as well in Internet Explorer. I've heard `Raphael.js` does it much better in IE.

So now I am trying to convert my `D3` code to `Raphael`, I made some progress, but I have some problems trying to add additional data or an id to a text element, which I can use to modify the text of a specific element. In `D3` I've used `.attr("weight", weight)` on a text element, and this works fine. But in `Raphael`, I can't get it to work.

I've tried giving the text an ID like this:

```
var text = paper.text((y * 50) + 20, (i * 50) + 15, weight).attr({
        fill: '#000'
    });
    text.attr({
        "font-size": 16,
            "font-family": "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
    });

    text.id = weight;
```

But still no luck in logging that ID. If it is not clear why I need this ID, check the before mentioned jsFiddle I made with D3, I need to get a specific element to change its text.

```
var grossRisks = [{
"weight": "1",
    "number": "5"
 }, {
 "weight": "4",
    "number": "6"
 }];

function populateChart(riskArray) {
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("text"),
    attr;
var loops = riskArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
    var obj = riskArray[i];

    for (var x = 0; x < element.length; x++) {
        attr = element[x];
        if (/^text/.test(attr.nodeName)) {
            console.log(
                "Weight: " + attr.getAttribute("weight"));
            if (attr.getAttribute("weight") == obj.weight) {
                attr.textContent = obj.number;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried multiple things like making a new set and adding data to that set, but I don't know where to go from that point, like how do I change the text of a set with a specific ID?

```
newSet[i] = paper.set();
    newSet[i].push(rect, text);

    newSet[i].attr({
        cursor: 'pointer'
    }).data('weight', weight);

    newSet[i].click(function () {
         console.log(this.id("weight"));
    });
```

The not working code of `Raphael` can be found in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Warforce/G94sQ/16/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues are

1. You get the raw DOM nodes, and not the RaphaelJS wrapped objects (*because you use `document.getElementsByTagName`*)
2. You set `data` but try to access it through `attr`.
3. In the fiddle, the `newSet` is not correctly built becuase you use the `i` variable which goes from 1 to 5.. to calculate the index you need to account for both of the loop counter.

So the changes made are

When populating the `newSet`

```
var index = (i*5) + y;
newSet[index] = paper.set();
```

When clearing and populating the chart use `newSet`

```
newSet[x].forEach(function(item){
    if (item.type=='text')
        attr=item;
});
```

to get the text node.
Working demo at Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/G94sQ/22/

---

You can ofcourse use `id` to simplify the code

To assign an `id` just use `text.id = 'your-id'`

When creating the `newSet`

```
text.id = 'weight-'+weight;
```

and when clearing/populating

```
attr = paper.getById('weight-'+obj.weight);
```

Working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/G94sQ/23/

(***additionally***: you are using jquery 1.11 in which the `.toggle` method just shows/hide the element and does not rotate the `click` functions as earlier versions. So I changed your code to 1.4.2 as a quick fix..)

Comment: Wow, you do not know how thankful I am, I've been working on it for a couple of hours now, trying everything. You even fixed that button! Amazing, thanks for your effort.

Comment: Thanks for listing those issues, I did not even realise I was making those, i won't make them again. Thanks again!